# Plot legend problems using R. Help removing excessive white space in legend box

Tags: r, plot, graphics, legend

I am creating a plot of some hydrology data and I am having trouble with the legend. The legend has a large amount of blank space around the text. I have tried using `par(mar= list)`, `cex`, `x.intersp`, and anything else I could find with no luck. I can't post images yet, but there is a link below. This is all of the code I am using to create the plot and legend. The `abline()` below indicates the mean value of the data and that is what I am putting in the legend. I have researched on the site and I can make it work using `mtext()` or legend(no bg or box) and `rect()`, but it seems like I am missing something. I am fairly new to R, but I have written code in the past. I am using RStudio version 0.99.903 and R version 3.2.2.

```
plot(dataFile$time_s,dataFile$w_cmps, type = "l",col="grey50", 
     xlim = c(0,18.5), ylim = c(-7,7), xlab = "Time (s)", ylab = "w (cm/s)", 
     main = "Vertical Velocity", xaxt="n")

axis(side = 1, at = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18), 
     labels = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18))

abline(h = mean_w, col = "black", lty = 3, lwd = 4)

legend("bottomleft","Mean w", lty = 3, col = "red", 
       xjust = 1, cex = 1, bg = "grey75", trace = TRUE, ncol = 1, xpd = NA, 
       seg.len = 1, y.intersp = 0.25, x.intersp = 0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you [manually resize](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15448900/6455166) the plot window after plotting?  That's the only way I can reproduce your problem; otherwise the legend box is tightly bound to the legend itself.

Comment: Use `png`, `pdf` or one of the other graphics devices that write to a file to produce plots for publications and presentations. That way you can specify the size of the plot.

Comment: I was using the "zoom" window in RStudio. I think this problem is related to the IDE. Based on your feedback, I tried using the "Save as" feature in RStudio and the image was still flawed when saving as a PNG or PDF.I just ran the script in the R console and the graphic was fine. Thanks for the feedback.